# issue with Cmake while configuring opencv sources

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-2012, cmake

i installed opencv2 ,python ,cmake and visual studio for an image processing project following this link https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html

but while configuring in cmake following errors are shown

```
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:872 (message):
Download: Local copy of opencv_ffmpeg.dll has invalid MD5 hash:
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e (expected:
89c783eee1c47bfc733f08334ec2e31c)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
3rdparty/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.cmake:10 (ocv_download)
cmake/OpenCVFindLibsVideo.cmake:206 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:536 (include)


Downloading opencv_ffmpeg.dll...
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:895 (file):
file DOWNLOAD HASH mismatch

for file: 


[D:/opencv/sources/3rdparty/ffmpeg/downloads/89c783eee1c47bfc733f08334ec2e31c/opencv_ffmpeg.dll]
      expected hash: [89c783eee1c47bfc733f08334ec2e31c]
        actual hash: [d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e]

Call Stack (most recent call first):
3rdparty/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.cmake:10 (ocv_download)
cmake/OpenCVFindLibsVideo.cmake:206 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:536 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:899 (message):
Failed to download opencv_ffmpeg.dll.  Status=6;"couldn't resolve host name"
Call Stack (most recent call first):
3rdparty/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.cmake:10 (ocv_download)
cmake/OpenCVFindLibsVideo.cmake:206 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:536 (include)
```

does anybody have idea how to solve this ?

Comment: I think the easiest way around is to change expected hash to the actual one in OpenCVUtils.cmake file. Be aware that this error might point out to corrupted or faked library being installed (or just be a mistake by opencv staff), so I would suggest you to check real hash from ffmpeg home page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV 3.0.0 "configure" fails, ffmpeg not downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932915/opencv-3-0-0-configure-fails-ffmpeg-not-downloaded)

Comment: thanks for help .kindly guide me further ,if it's a configuration error or i need to reinstall softwares?

Comment: i tried a number of methods and now i'm getting the following error     CMake Error: The source directory "D:/opencv" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.:                     kindly help me out?