# error building from source the opencv4.4.0 in cmake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am now building from source the opencv4.4.0 with  windows10, vs2019, cmake-gui-3.18.1. after configuration in cmake-gui, i click the generator button, and i get the error message below. I am new to opencv, and i couldn't figure out how to solve it. Anyone who can help, THANKS.

Search for information on the Internet, download IIPCV, find E:\opencv\opencv-4.4.0.cache\ippicv, CMAKE still has errors

```
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVDownload.cmake:202 (message):
  IPPICV: Download failed: 6;"Couldn't resolve host name"

  For details please refer to the download log file:

  E:/opencv/opencv-4.4.0/build/CMakeDownloadLog.txt
```

Comment: If you received a `Couldn't resolve host name` warning, it should have also printed `Couldn't download files from the Internet. Please check the Internet access on this host.`. Did you check your internet access on that machine? Also, there was a similar question asked on this site before, with a potentially helpful response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33095689/3987854).

Comment: If you wont use IPP then closing the flag can help: `-D WTIH_IPP = OFF `

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV CMake downloads `ippicv` to the path `$(YOUR_OPENCV_SOURCE_DIR)/.cache/ippicv`. If CMake detects target file already in the directory, CMake skips downloading and proceed with the exsiting file.

I found the file name of `ippicv` for OpenCV 4.4.0 as following:

**879741a7946b814455eee6c6ffde2984-ippicv_2020_win_intel64_20191018_general.zip**

The file you downloaded must exist in .../.cache/ippicv/ with the name above.

Comment: Part of the name could differ to your downloaded file depends on you CPU.